# Python to look for each particular item in a row in 1 file is present in a row in another file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner to Python and trying to write a code that would basically look for a particular element in one csv file and see if it matches it in a row of another csv file. i have tens of thousands of rows in both file to do this match. I am unable to do this lookup in any efficient manner and takes longer time. but somehow my below code to look up for two conditions doesn't seems to work. can somebody point out what wrong am I doing here.

Sample file1 data

```
Event_Type,Exch_Time,Recv_Time,Sqn_No,Sec_Status,Sec_SubStatus,Bid_Price,Bid_Size,Ask_Price,Ask_Size,High_Price,Low_Price,Open_Price,Volume,Trade_Price,Trade_Size,Imb_Type,Imb_Vol,Imb_PairedVol,Imb_Ref_Price
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,05-JUL-2017 00:00:00.000000000,07-JUL-2017 08:46:40.937664512,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
XOBJ_EVENT_EQUITY_REFRESH,05-JUL-2017 06:30:01.498694396,05-JUL-2017 06:30:01.498694396,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
XOBJ_EVENT_TRADING_ACTION,05-JUL-2017 06:50:00.011149000,05-JUL-2017 06:50:00.011963671,663,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
XOBJ_EVENT_TRADING_ACTION,05-JUL-2017 07:00:00.000088000,05-JUL-2017 07:00:00.000902786,975,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
XOBJ_EVENT_EQUITY_QUOTE,05-JUL-2017 07:00:00.009227000,05-JUL-2017 07:00:00.009974141,1295,XTRST_OPEN/XTRSST_OPEN_REGULAR,XTRST_CLOSED/XTRSST_CLOSED_REGULAR,
216.4000,677,,0,,,,,,,,,,
XOBJ_EVENT_EQUITY_QUOTE,05-JUL-2017 07:00:01.070149000,05-JUL-2017 07:00:01.070872371,1482,XTRST_OPEN/XTRSST_OPEN_REGULAR,XTRST_OPEN/XTRSST_OPEN_REGULAR,217.
3000,2654,218.1000,794,,,,,,,,,,
```

File 2 also contains similar type data

my simple codes is as follow -

```
File1 = open(sourceFile1, 'r')
file1Reader = csv.DictReader(File1, delimiter= ',')
File2 = open(sourceFile2, 'r')
file2Reader = csv.DictReader(File2, delimiter= ',')
for row in file1Reader:
    for item in file2Reader:
        if "EQUITY" in row['Event_Type'] and row['Sqn_No'] == item['Sqn_No']:
            print "Found Match"
            break
```

Comment: Do you have to compare whole rows or just specific column values?

Comment: type of row['Event_Type'] is string or something else?.. also when you use break it won't find any other line matching same condition in second file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing that's wrong here is that after the first iteration of the `file2Reader` there is nothing more to iterate to as your reader has reached the `File2` EOF - you'd actually have to rewind your `File2` back to the beginning (`File2.seek(0)`) to iterate over it again. Also, that would be incredibly inefficient way to do it as I/O is rather slow even with an SSD.

Also, `csv.DictReader()` is a handy convenience reader but it can be many times slower than the regular `csv.reader()` so if you're worried about performance (which definitely should be a factor if you have 10k+ results to compare with another 10k+ results) it's much better to create a header map and use that when you want to access rows by column name.

So, first staying with your approach, heavy on I/O, you can modify it to:

```
import csv

with open(sourceFile1, "r") as f1, open(sourceFile2, "r") as f2:
    l1 = csv.reader(f1)  # reader for sourceFile1
    h1 = next(l1)  # get the header from sourceFile1
    c1 = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(h1)}  # build column index map for sourceFile1
    l2 = csv.reader(f2)  # reader for sourceFile2
    h2 = next(l2)  # get the header from sourceFile2
    c2 = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(h2)}  # build column index map for sourceFile2
    for r1 in l1:  # iterate over each row of sourceFile1
        for r2 in l2:   # iterate over each row of sourceFile2
            if "EQUITY" in r1[c1["Event_Type"]] and r1[c1["Sqn_No"]] == r2[c2["Sqn_No"]]:
                print("Match found!")
                break
        f2.seek(0)  # rewind sourceFile2 back to the beginning
        next(l2)  # skip the header of sourceFile2
```

But if you're only going to compare a single column value (like `Sqn_No` in your case), or a slew of columns, provided memory is not an issue (and it shouldn't be for tens of thousands of entries unless each entry is megabytes long) it's much better idea to create a lookup map in memory by reading one of the files and extracting the needed fields, then just do fast lookups when iterating over the second file, something like:

```
import csv

with open(sourceFile1, "r") as f1, open(sourceFile2, "r") as f2:
    # we'll use the sourceFile2 as a lookup source
    reader = csv.reader(f2)  # reader for sourceFile2
    header = next(reader)  # get the header from sourceFile2
    columns = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(header)}  # build column index map for sourceFile2
    lookup_map = {row[columns["Sqn_No"]] for row in reader}  #  simple set holding the values
    # now deal with sourceFile1 in a single iteration
    reader = csv.reader(f1)  # reader for sourceFile1
    header = next(reader)  # get the header from sourceFile1
    columns = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(header)}  # build column index map for sourceFile1
    for row in reader:  # iterate over each row of sourceFile1
        if "EQUITY" in row[columns["Event_Type"]] and row[columns["Sqn_No"]] in lookup_map:
            print("Match found!")
```

You can place anything in the lookup_map - the key can be a tuple if you want to compare multiple column values, and you can add it a value (so turn it from a `set` to a `dict`) to point to some more data if you need further comparison. How will you construct your lookup is completely up to you. You can also further increase performance by caching the lookup indexes instead of storing them in a lookup map.

Of course, this all assumes that the both files have the required columns and that each row if properly filled (even with empty values) - otherwise you'd have to check if a particular index even exists in your CSV row but, again, I'll let you deal with the edge cases.

Comment: Many thanks for your response, it really helps and your second approach is something that i will go with as that much faster.